# Remove build number from version number: 1.3.0.342 should become 1.3.0

Tags: bash, sed, grep

For a Jenkins build script I need to remove the build number from the version. I need to end up with `MajorVersion.MinorVersion.BugfixVersion`. These numbers are not fixed to one digit. If they already have three version numbers, nothing should happen:

```
1.30.0.342 -> 1.30.0
100.3.0.32 -> 100.3.0
1.3.1234.3 -> 1.3.1234
1.3.0 -> 1.3.0
```

How can I do this properly with grep / sed?

My input comes from a variable

```
export VERSION="$(gulp config --silent --getWidgetAttr=version)"
```

Comment: What does your input look like? Is it in a file, or already in a shell variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need three sections (MajorVersion.MinorVersion.BugfixVersion)

you could get this with "cut"

```
echo "1.30.0.342" | cut -d '.' -f1-3
```

Comment: what does `-f1-3` stand for?

Comment: -f1-3 = fields one to three

Answer (score 2):

If only extracting 3-component version numbers is needed, without acting on their components individually, [Vafa's helpful `cut` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41784736/45375) is clearly the simplest choice.

Here's an `awk` solution that may be of interest if component-individual processing is needed (inside the `awk` script, `$1` represents the 1st component, `$2` the second, ...):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="." } { if (NF > 3) { NF = 3 } } 1' <<'EOF'
1.30.0.342
100.3.0.32
1.3.1234.3
1.3.0
EOF

1.30.0
100.3.0
1.3.1234
1.3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

With grep, if the variables are stored in `infile`:

```
$ grep -Eo '^([^.]+\.){2}[^.]+' infile
1.30.0
100.3.0
1.3.1234
1.3.0
```

This anchors the pattern at the beginning of the line, looks for "one or more of not-a-period, followed by a period" (repeated twice), followed by "one or more of not-a-period". The `-o` flag retains only the matched part.

Alternatively, in pure (and obscure) Bash with parameter expansion (requires extended globs, `shopt -s extglob`):

```
$ vnum=1.3.1234.3
$ echo "${vnum%"${vnum##+([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]])}"}"
1.3.1234
$ vnum=1.3.0
$ echo "${vnum%"${vnum##+([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]])}"}"
1.3.0
```

This combines "remove from end of string", `"${var%pattern}"` with "remove (longest match) from beginning of string", `"${var##pattern}"`, where `pattern` for removing from the end is the expansion of a "remove from the beginning pattern".

`extglob` is required to match "one or more" in `+([[:digit:}})`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this as well, using a here string:

```
cut -f1-3 -d. <<< "1.30.0.342"
```

If the build number is in a variable called `build`, then:

```
cut -f1-3 -d. <<< "$build"
```

`cut` command extracts values from a delimited line of text.

- `-f1-3` => extract fields 1 through 3
- `-d.`   => . is the delimiter, no need to enclose it in quotes